# How many different numbers can $a_1 \circ a_2 \circ \dots \circ a_n$ result in?

Tags: field-theory

Let's say I have $i=1,2,\dots n$ and $a_i$ are numbers. I would like to know if $\circ$ is a placeholder for $+$ and $\cdot$ how many different numbers can be the result of
$$a_1 \circ a_2 \circ \dots \circ a_n?$$

If I am being unclear, here is an example with i=3:
There are generally 8 different numbers and they are in
$$
\{
x+y+z, x(y+z), y(z+x), z(x+y),x+yz, y+zx, z+xy, xyz
\}
$$
I'm having trouble being consistent at counting them up for larger i. I have two main problems: Discarding duplicates and changing the order of operations with parenthesis. Especially with multiple parentheses. Without that ability I don't know how to come up with a general formula.

What sub field of mathematics usually cares about questions of this nature?

Comment: Are you allowing for arbitrary order of operations (i.e., you are allowed to put parentheses wherever you want?), or is multiplication always done before addition?

Comment: @DonThousand I would like to let the parenthesis define the order of operations. In my example with i=3, I used the convention multiplication before addition. Sorry for the confusion.